# Accessing hardware registers in Linux userspace

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I wpuld like to write to hardware registers on OMAP3530 in Linux userspace. Please, find below code. Mmap returns error:

Memory map failed. error -1

mmap: Permission denied

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BASE_ADDRESS 0x48050000

int main()
{
        int mem;
        unsigned int *value;
        void *ptr;

        /* Open /dev/mem */
        if ((mem = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY | O_SYNC)) == -1)
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open /dev/mem\n"), exit(1);

        ptr = mmap (0, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mem, BASE_ADDRESS);

        if(ptr == (void *) -1) {
                printf("Memory map failed. error %i\n", ptr);
                perror("mmap");
                }

        value = (unsigned int*)(ptr + 0x4BC+((1-1)*0x90)+(0*0x04));
        *value = 479*799*3-4;
        printf("value = %i", value);

        value = (unsigned int*)(ptr + 0x4C4+((-1)*0x90));
        *value = 1;
        printf("value = %i", value);

        value = (unsigned int*)(ptr + 0x4C8+((-1)*0x90));
        *value = 1;
        printf("value = %i", value);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [mmap()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap) says (emphasis mine):

> The `mmap()` function shall fail if:
>
> **EACCES**
>
> The *fildes* argument is not open for read, regardless of the protection specified, or ***fildes* is not open for write and `PROT_WRITE`
>   was specified for a `MAP_SHARED` type mapping**.

Since you specify `PROT_WRITE`, the file should be open for write. Your code only opens it for read.

Comment: Changed mem = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC), still got an error: Memory map failed. error 1
mmap: Operation not permitted

Comment: upps, sorry, I got that error for x86, but for ARM OMAP3530 it works. thanks!